# Crontab not run job and change job

Tags: cron

I've set 'Crontab' with root user and -e key but Cron is not running my jobs and after little time, my job is removed and replaced with other text!!!!

The jobs set:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot noip2
# Agape
5 2 * * * aria2c -c -x16 -s16 -t120 -j2 -k 1M -i "/home/Downloadlink.txt" -d "/home/Download/" -l /home/AriaLog/`date '+\%Y\%m\%d'`.log --log-level=notice
55 6 * * * pkill aria2c
```

In syslog, Cron says `Run Noip2` but not run this

Comment: i'm run ubuntu on mk802 arm board

Comment: Please explain more clearly. Did you run `sudo crontab -e`? Or do you have an actual `root` account enabled, logged in as `root` and ran `crontab -e`? How is your job removed? What text is it replaced by? Do you mean that the crontab is deleted? Please [edit] your question (don't comment) and clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What hour is it? That is configured to run at 02:05 and 06:55 respectively. So the first thing to check would be that the date is right (even if it IS 2 AM, your system may think it's a different hour, or be running on a different timezone).

My first check would be to run `date` and verify that the time is right and it should have been run. Only then start checking things like "is cron running" (apparently it is), changing the hour to `*`and so on.